# Do procedural skies typically cause viewport lag?

Tags: procedural, world

I'm new to procedural skies and I'm trying two payware products for Blender: "Nm-8 Skies" and "Procedural Sky System", both available from Blender Market. While the results from both are beautiful, they slow my viewport to a crawl. Procedural Sky System especially makes the viewport too laggy to use when Viewport Shading is set to Material Preview or Rendered. Doesn't matter whether I'm employing Cycles or Eevee. **Are procedural skies known to be laggy in Blender?** A limitation I need to learn to live with? Or is there a solution or workaround? Thanks. Blender 3.2.2, Windows 11

Comment: Seems like you already answered your question

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't something fundamental about procedural skies I was not understanding.

Comment: Well, procedural basically means "made with math", so the more complex the math, the more performance heavy it becomes. A simple "cloudy sky" made with a single noise texture won't lag, but more complex clouds made from multiple noise textures added/mixed together with their vectors multiplied by a detailed musgrave texture or something similar, will start to slow down. As with any shader graph, the more nodes/mixes you add, the more "performance hungry" it becomes.

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone. The viewport slowness appears to have resolved itself for both products. In the case of Procedural Sky System, it appears it was still compiling while I was trying to work with the scene, so that may have slowed things at first.